# To get the value in row from webgrid and pass it to the controller

Tags: javascript, jquery, model-view-controller

I am getting value in Column , following is the code.

```
grid.Column(columnName: "Name", header: "Name",format: @<text>  
      <span id="Name">@item.Name</span></text>, canSort: false),
```

want to use this value in function which I have called on delete button

```
function DeleteEnterpriseID() {
        var checkID = $(".edit-mode:checked").map(function () {
            return this.value;
        }).toArray();
        alert(checkID.join(","));

        if (confirm("Are you sure you want to delete?") == true) {
            var url = "@Url.Action("DeleteEnterpriseIdDetails")";
            var pname = $('#Name').val();  //// Here I want that value from the clicked row so that I can pass that to controller.
            alert(pname);
            $.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });
            $.post(url, { Pname: pname, EnterpriseID: checkID.join(",") })
            .success(function (response) {
                if (response != null && response.success) {
                    alert(response.responseText);
                    window.location.href = response.newurl;

                } else {
                    alert(response.responseText);
                }
            })
            .error(function (response) { alert("error"); });
        }
        else {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

But I am getting blank value for Name from clicked row. 
Kindly assist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be:

```
var pname = $('#Name').text();
```

Because its a `span` tag and not an input element. `val()` works for input elements.